# Using current logged in user to request user Attributes fom Active Directory using Java

Tags: java, active-directory

I mainly ask, is it possible to estahblish a connection to AD,Kerberos to get user attrubutes without the need to provide username and password in a java programm.

Using username and password it works fine to request Attributes using Java.
But is it easy possible use a kerberoes ticket or a connection pool in any way?
Otherwise i have to save the user password which im not very into it.

Thanks for your Time!